# finding a variable in an infinite series for every odd index

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this following series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1-\cos\left(n\pi \:\right)}{a^n}$$ & it's given that this series is equal to $1$. I have to solve for $a$ and i noticed that every even '$n$', the series is $0$, and every odd '$n$' it's $2/a^n$. I tried dividing it into two separate series one for odd and one for even but no luck. any help?

Comment: Using image links is advised against, I recommend putting the content from the image into the post using the available LaTeX functionality.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show your attempt "dividing it into two separate series one for odd and one for even". Hint for a more direct calculation: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac x{1-x}$ if $|x|<1.$ Apply this to $x=1/a$ and to $x=-1/a.$

Answer (score 1):

Your series is simply

$$\sum_{n=1}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{a^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{a^{2n-1}}$$

Try to take it from here, taking into account that for $\;a\in\Bbb C\;,\;\;|a|<1\;$ :

$$\frac1{1-a}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{2n+1}\;,\;\;\text{ and}\;\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{2n}=\frac1{1-a^2}\;\ldots$$

Comment: I was to solve but you did it fine, my old friend Don!

Comment: @Mikasa Hi there, my dear Mikasa. I hope you're doing fine, my friend.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your answer Don